# Tradução de Post Traumatic Stress Disorder(Estresse Pós Traumatico)

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, tradução, tradução-inglês

[Post Traumatic Stress Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder) - de acordo com o Wikipedia - é *"um distúrbio mental que pode se desenvolver em uma pessoa após a exposição a um evento traumatico(...)"*. A tradução comum que eu vejo por aí é **Estresse Pós Traumático**, porém que acho que não é a tradução correta. Pra mim o correto deveria ser **Distúrbio de Trauma Pós Estresse**(ou Trauma Pós Estresse apenas), ou algo nesse sentido.

O fato é que a pessoa desenvolve um distúrbio traumático **após um estresse** e não um estresse **após um trauma**, como é sugerido na tradução do português. Ou seja, ela desenvolve um trauma após uma situação estressante. Por exemplo um veterano de guerra, que volta da guerra com um trauma(uma sociopatia, por ex.) após uma situação de estresse(um enfrentamento com um inimigo durante a guerra, por ex.).

Em outras palavras o [estresse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_stress)(sentimento de tensão e pressão) é a causa, e o [trauma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_trauma)(dano mental resultante de um doloroso evento) é o resultado. Portanto **Trauma Pós Estresse** e não **Estresse Pós Trauma**. Estou correto ?

Comment: a tradução correta não seria *Transtorno de Estresse Pós-Traumático (TEPT)*. Essa é o que a wikipedia em português retorna.

Comment: E eu acho que é um estresse que ocorre após um trauma. Tu teves um trauma numa guerra e criou um estresse por causa disso...Mas eu apenas acho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tradução está correta. Em medicina chamamos de "transtorno (ou síndrome) do estresse pós-traumático" e, na verdade, **o trauma ocorre primeiro e depois é que vem o período de estresse decorrente daquele trauma.**

Dr. [**Drauzio Varella**](https://drauziovarella.com.br/doencas-e-sintomas/transtorno-do-estresse-pos-traumatico/) faz o seguinte comentário sobre o transtorno:

> O transtorno do estresse pós-traumático (TEPT) é um distúrbio da ansiedade caracterizado por um conjunto de sinais e sintomas físicos, psíquicos e emocionais em decorrência de o portador ter sido vítima ou testemunha de atos violentos ou de situações traumáticas que, em geral, representaram ameaça à sua vida ou à vida de terceiros. Quando se recorda do fato, ele revive o episódio, como se estivesse ocorrendo naquele momento e com a mesma sensação de dor e sofrimento que o agente estressor provocou. Essa recordação, conhecida como revivescência, desencadeia alterações neurofisiológicas e mentais.
>
> Aproximadamente entre 15% e 20% das pessoas que, de alguma forma, estiveram envolvidas em casos de violência urbana, agressão física, abuso sexual, terrorismo, tortura, assalto, sequestro, acidentes, guerra, catástrofes naturais ou provocadas, desenvolvem esse tipo de transtorno. No entanto, a maioria só procura ajuda dois anos depois das primeiras crises.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a tua pergunta, eu acredito que a tradução está correta. Na própria Wikipedia em inglês diz que a causa é um trauma (e não um estresse).

> Posttraumatic stress disorder (PTSD)[note 1] is a mental disorder that
>   can develop after a person is **exposed to a traumatic event**, such as
>   sexual assault, warfare, traffic collisions, or other threats on a
>   person's life.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder)

Também na wikipedia em inglês diz que a causa é um trauma:

> Causes - Exposure to a traumatic event

Fonte: [Posttraumatic stress disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder)